# Do something if opening Activity from notification

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make my activity do something if it's opened from a notification. In my BroadcastReceiver, I have this:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
startServiceIntent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
startServiceIntent.putExtras(extras);
context.startService(startServiceIntent);

...

PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);
```

And in my main activity, I try to call it:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
if(extras.getBoolean("fromNotification")) {
Toast.makeText(this, "from notification", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
} else {
Toast.makeText(this, "extras = " + extras, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Problem is that the `else` statement always fires, saying `extras` is null.

What am I missing here?

UPDATE:

`BroadcastReceiver`

```
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
startServiceIntent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
context.startService(startServiceIntent);
```

`MainActivity`

```
boolean fromNotification = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("fromNotification", false);
if (fromNotification) {
Toast.makeText(this, "from notification", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
Toast.makeText(this, fromNotification + " elsewhere", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a little mixup in your code. You are creating and extra bundle but you are assigning your boolean not to the extra bundle.

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
startServiceIntent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
startServiceIntent.putExtras(extras);
context.startService(startServiceIntent);
```

Change that to:

```
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
Bundle extras = startServiceIntent.getExtras();
extras.putBoolean("fromNotification", true);
startServiceIntent.putExtras(extras);
context.startService(startServiceIntent);
```

Update:

Personally I don't use the Bundle way, I just use the intent.putExtra() methods, but than I need to change the way I get them to this:

```
boolean fromNotification = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("fromNotification", false);
if (fromNoticiation) {
    // I was called by notification
} else {
    // started from somewhere else
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a NullPointerException from this line: `extras.putBoolean("fromNotification", true);` I don't have to use a Bundle. Would anything else have to change using `intent.putExtra()`?

Comment: Just use the intent.putExtra() variant and skip the bundle stuff. The code you need to get the boolean is already part of my answer (see updated part). The nullpointer is probably because startServiceIntent has not yet a bundle stored as extra. So you could also just make `Bundle extras = new Bundle()` to fix that.

Comment: Not getting the NullPointerExcpetion anymore, using the intent.putExtra() variant, but it's still firing as false. I updated my original post to show what I have now.

Comment: You might want to try to add an action as Tavian said? Otherwise the code looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can set action to your intent and register a receiver for it so when it is launched your broadcast receiver will (obviously) receive that message and to confirm it is the right one you can check like this:

```
if(receivedIntent.getAction().equals("yourAction"))//do sth
```

And to add action to your intent use this code:

```
PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1000, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class).setAction("yourAction"), 0);
```

You also want to use 1000 for request code instead of 0 because in android 4.3 a lot of users are experiencing problem opening notifications... So that thing fixes it.

Your else statement always fires because the extras you get are null and that is because  your code where you send the intent is wrong...
Use this:

```
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
startServiceIntent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
context.startService(startServiceIntent);
```